# Imacros: input random var from extraction

Tags: imacros

I have a working imacros script that extracts 3 urls from a page, creates variables from them, moves on to a different page and then inputs one of the variables into a form. Right now I just hardcode {{!VAR1}}, but what I would like to do is make the input random from the three variables. So instead of this:

CONTENT={{!VAR1}}

I would like to have either {{!VAR1}} or {{!VAR2}} or {{!VAR3}} be the input randomly.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use JavaScript scripting http://wiki.imacros.net/Web_Scripting

With use of JavaScript you can find some random functions do this.